# How to escape < and " in xslt file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to output`<foreignObject id="`in my xslt file, so I wrote this
`<xsl:text><foreignObject id="</xsl:text>` 
but it looks like it doesn't work in this way, I don't know how to escape this, any reply will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could do:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;foreignObject id="</xsl:text>
```

However, I think it's safe to say that if you need this, you must be doing something wrong. Your XSLT should concentrate on creating the output tree and let the markup be created by the processor's serializer.

Comment: Thanks, because I'm trying to convert the xml tag to html tag, I don't know how to populate the tag and value from xml at the same time, so I'm doing in this way, don't know if it works

Comment: I suggest you ask another question about that. Or look at the countless examples of converting XML to HTML here and elsewhere.